# How to get all values from a table which are not present in other table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two table say a and b

```
SQL> desc a;

 Name                                      Type
 ----------------------------------------- ----------------------------
 ID                                        NUMBER(38)    
 NAME                                      VARCHAR2(10)


SQL> desc b;

 Name                                      Type
 ----------------------------------------- ----------------------------
 ID                                        NUMBER(38)    
 NAME                                      VARCHAR2(10)
```

SQL> select * from a;

```
    ID NAME
     1 a
     1 a
     1 a
     2 b
     2 b
     3 c
     3 c
     4 d
```

SQL> select * from b;

```
    ID NAME
     1 a
     2 b
```

my output should look like

```
    ID NAME
     1 a
     1 a
     2 b
     3 c
     3 c
     4 d
```

When I do

SQL> select * from a minus select * from b;

```
    ID NAME
     3 c
     4 d
```

but this is not what I want.. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Why have a column called `id` that is not a unique id on the table?  Some naming conventions don't make sense.

In any case, you have a problem because you have exactly duplicate rows, with no way to distinguish them.  Fortunately, Oracle has a solution.  You can use `row_number()` or `rownum` to create a unique key, and then use this for removing the duplicates.

```
select a.*
from (select a.*, row_number() over (partition by id, name order by id) as seqnum
      from a
     ) a left outer join
     (select b.*, row_number() over (partition by id, name order by id) as seqnum
      from b
     ) b
     on a.id = b.id and a.seqnum = b.seqnum
where b.id is NULL;
```

Comment: +1 because it's the only correct solution, although I'd use a MINUS instead of a LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Comment: thanks Gordon. but when I increase the number of columns from two to three or four or more, i an not getting accurate answer. How to modify the query in that case

Answer (score 0):

One approach is

```
select id,type from
(
   select rownum,id,type from table1 minus select rownum,id,type from table2 
) temp
```

Comment: Although this would happen to work on the data in the example, it wouldn't work if table `a` contained two more rows like `1, 'a'`.

Comment: i tried the query but that is not solving the problem. My problem is table 'a' is imported from a csv file and there are chances of having same row more than once. So i need to check the occurrences of rows and say how many duplicates are found. For doing this is need to literally subtract rows and take remaining.